# How to Direct Output from a SAS Procedure to the Log or Output Window?

Tags: file, sas, proc-sql

How do I send output from a SAS Procedure to the Output or Log window?

Answer (score 2):

By default, SAS procedure results are directed to Output window.
I do not think you can direct them to Log window.

However, I think you can direct them in an external file using PROC PRINTTO.

For more control, you can use ODS DOCUMENT or ODS OUTPUT. Read manual for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily redirect the output of the log window with the proc printto as suggested, here is an examble

proc printto log="c:\temp\log.txt";
run;

*YOUR CODE*

*code to stop writing on the external file;

proc printto new;
run;